# Rewriting clumsy code that gets the value of a nested property in JS object

Tags: javascript

I have an API that returns JSON, where the value that I need is stored in either one of the two object properties:

```
data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
```

or

```
data.value.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
```

The code that I'm using is pretty clumsy. At first, I used something like this:

```
if (data && data.d && data.d.GetContextWebInformation && data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue) {
    this.options.token = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
} else {
// check for second one
```

Now I've rewritten it using try/catch, and it looks a bit cleaner, but still clumsy:

```
    var token; 
    try {
        // If Verbosity was odata=verbose:
        token = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
    } catch (ex) {
        try {
            // If Verbosity was odata=nometadata or odata=minimalmetadata:
            token = data.value.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
        } catch (ex) {
            throw 'Unable to obtain authorization token.';
        }
    } finally {
        if (token) { this.options.token = token; }
    }
```

What would be a better way to write the same code for a cleaner, nicer look? If that matters, I need to support IE9 so probably can't use newer language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain the token exists in either of the objects you can do:

First check for the existence of the value in data.

```
var value = data.d || data.value;
```

then access the value to get the token

```
var token = value && value.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
```

```js
var value = data.d || data.value;

var token = value && value.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;


if (token) {
  this.options.token = token;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use `getIn` function:

```js
function getIn(pathArray, obj) {
  var tmp = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
    if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(pathArray[i])) {
      tmp = tmp[pathArray[i]];
      continue;
    }
    return undefined;
  }
  return tmp;
}

var token = getIn(['d', 'GetContextWebInformation', 'FormDigestValue'], data) ||
            getIn(['value', 'GetContextWebInformation', 'FormDigestValue'], data);

if (token) {
  this.options.token = token;
}
```

Comment: I would not require a pathArray list, but a path String like `"d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue"`, it would make the calling code cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `{}` fallbacks at each nesting level.

```
((data && (data.d || data.value) || {}).GetContextWebInformation || {}).FormDigestValue
```

I'm not saying it's more readable in non-trivial cases, though.
In the bright future we might be able to use [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) e.g. `var foo = a?.b?.c?.d`